# CSS3 - Transition

Tags: css, hover, css-transitions

I have a little problem with CSS.
I'm following a book to learn CSS3 and I just discovered the function Transition.
So I decided to make an attempt and I can not figure out where I'm wrong, I hope you can help me.

This is my Index.html file

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="box"></div>
<div class="ssin"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

nothing special ! and this is the main.css

```
.box{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #333333;
}

.ssin{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}

.box:hover .ssin{
    width: 500
}
```

i think the problem is around here ...

```
.box:hover .ssin{
    width: 500;
}
```

If I hove .box nothing happen, theoretically it should change the width of ssin div.

Could you please help me (I know this is stupid, but I'am still learning)

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the HTML you have posted there, `ssin` is not inside `box`. `.box:hover .ssin` selects something with the class `ssin` inside `box`. I believe what you want here is the adjacent sibling selector: `.box:hover + .ssin`

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the measurements from the `width` property, but your markup won't allow what you're trying to achieve.

`.box:hover .ssin` will only make trigger when `.ssin` is a child of `.box`. If you want to animate the width of `.ssin` when `.box` is hovered, you'll have to use the adjacent sibling selector in CSS (`+`):

```
.box:hover + .ssin {
    width: 500px;
}
```

If you want the element to be animated, you need to add the relevant CSS properties too:

```
.ssin {
    -webkit-transition: width 0.2s linear;
       -moz-transition: width 0.2s linear;
            transition: width 0.2s linear;
}
```

Here's a [**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ph2jH/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
.box:hover .ssin{
    width: 500px;
}
```

i think `width: 500px;` is missing

Comment: Look at the markup. The selector `.box .ssin` doesn't match any element.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to look into CSS3 Transition, I will assume you are trying to increase the size of the box. SO, your markup is slightly wrong. The `ssin` should be inside the `.box`

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="ssin"></div>
</div>
```

And add the transition css to your code

```
.ssin {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
       -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
            transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
```

Comment: Why not just use the adjacent sibling selector, as demonstrated in my answer? It avoids any need to change his markup...

Comment: I can use both, but in this case Sibiling is not necessary.
I want to slide a div caption over box class.
I just added .ssin inside .box then i added overflow: hidden and -webkit-transition and it works.